Any way to schedule Postman Runner to trigger at a specific time of day for large .csv files?
I'm trying to schedule Postman to run a collection at 5:00 AM for around 30,000 requests with a .csv file. I need to run this Monday - Friday at 5:00 AM for the next two weeks with a different .csv file each time. Anyone figured out a way to do this? Looked into scheduling outside of Postman but I'm on iOS and seems like options are limited.
I tried to create a Postman Monitor but this is a short-term project that needs to run for the next two weeks, plus the file used will be different every time. Ran into the same problem trying to use the Schedule runs feature but received the Maximum iterations can be 50. error.

I don't use IOS but have you looked into running from the command line. https://learning.postman.com/docs/collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/.  If you schedule a task and use the CLI it might be what you want.

You can use the Postman CLI, but that has limitations on running from the Postman Cloud, so if its an internal API that you need to call, you will have issues.  The other options is the Newman CLI which runs locally on Node.JS.  Seems to be that the limiting factor here is IOS.  Can you not get access to a Windows PC that you can the inbuilt Microsoft Scheduler with either of the aforementioned CLI tools.  Or lastly use a CI tool like Azure Pipelines to manage the job for you.
